# Adding Count Post in Page

Tags: posts, pages, count

Question : **how to display post count in a page** like this picture : Showing 25 of 123 products

I mean in general. I use the custom theme and create a page that contains Categories. How to display text categories count per page for Categories Page. Example: Showing 25 of 123 products. 25 is the number of articles per page and 123 is the total articles for 1 category.

[image]

I have try  used

> Count Posts in a Category, Tag, or Custom Taxonomy plugin

by bitacre (shinraholdings.com).

wordpress.org/plugins/count-posts-in-a-category/

But it only show total count for all like this :

[image]

Using this shortcode :

*Showing [tax_count tax="dt_portfolio_category" slug="products-banner"] products*

How to modify it?
I have ask in their forum and web but still no answer.

Comment: There have been a couple of these posts answered in the passed, so please use the site search, there are a couple of nice ideas on site

Comment: hi @pieter-goosen, whether there are available as a plugin? I've been looking for in the form of plugins but I found everything is Post Views Count plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about woocommerce, this function is located in woocommerce/templates/loop/results-count.php

Here's the full code, you will get the logic if you go through it.

```
$paged    = max( 1, $wp_query->get( 'paged' ) );
$per_page = $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' );
$total    = $wp_query->found_posts;
$first    = ( $per_page * $paged ) - $per_page + 1;
$last     = min( $total, $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) * $paged );

if ( 1 == $total ) {
    _e( 'Showing the single result', 'woocommerce' );
} elseif ( $total <= $per_page || -1 == $per_page ) {
    printf( __( 'Showing all %d results', 'woocommerce' ), $total );
} else {
    printf( _x( 'Showing %1$d&ndash;%2$d of %3$d results', '%1$d = first, %2$d = last, %3$d = total', 'woocommerce' ), $first, $last, $total );
}
```

It's called on archive template page through the following function:

```
do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop');
```

Or you can build your own. Getting programmatically the number of posts on archive page can be called through:

```
$display_count = get_option('posts_per_page');
```

and you can figure the rest.

Comment: thank you for your help.I tested your code in woocommerce page and it works. but I mean in general. I use the the7 theme and create a page that contains a collection of some of the articles / posts. how to display text post count. Example: Showing 25 of 123 products. 25 is the number of articles per page and 123 is the total articles for 1 category. I've changed my question to add this sentence.

Comment: hi @koko5678, whether there are available as a plugin? I've been looking for in the form of plugins but I found everything is Post Views Count plugins.